# VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

Tags: python, numpy

estoy resolviendo problemas con números imaginarios y matrices, quiero eliminar el error

VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

```
from numpy import matrix
import numpy

gen = matrix (' 0.          232.39327235  -16.54930054     0.            0.            0. ;'       
            '   1.           40.           43.55710013    0.            0.            0.        ;'
            '   2.            0.           25.0753485      0.            0.            0.        ;'
            '   5.            0.           12.7309444     0.            0.            0.      ;'
            '   7.            0.           17.62345137     0.            0.            0.    ')
C1 = matrix (' 0.00000000+0.j          0.00000000+0.j          0.00000000-0.j 0.00000000-0.j          0.00000000-0.j          0.00000000+0.j;'
             '-0.08708275+0.01011859j -0.08846105+0.01073401j -0.08936566+0.01107736j  -0.09577387+0.01192692j -0.09436062+0.0118287j  -0.08708275+0.01011859j;'
             '-0.34566853-0.02646321j -0.35148330-0.02511487j -0.35525392-0.02446497j -0.38077009-0.02600493j -0.37521010-0.02531933j -0.34566853-0.02646321j;' 
             '-0.02177508+0.00024801j -0.02213150+0.00036441j -0.02236385+0.00042584j -0.02396895+0.00047002j -0.02361727+0.0004823j  -0.02177508+0.00024801j;'
             '-0.05029193+0.00828242j -0.05107535+0.00867789j -0.05159120+0.00890229j -0.05528916+0.00957272j -0.05447116+0.00947663j -0.05029193+0.00828242j;'
             '-0.05502352+0.0055352j  -0.05589884+0.00590995j -0.05647273+0.00611771j -0.06052280+0.00659123j -0.05963048+0.00654302j -0.05502352+0.0055352j ')

for d in range(0,2):
   C1[(gen[d,0],d)]= C1[(gen[d,0],d)]+1

print C1
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estás indizando usando índices no enteros, en concreto usas floats para indizar. Esto se debe a que al hacer `C1[(gen[d,0],d)]`, `gen[d,0]` retornar un valor de `gen`, que es un array  de tipo `np.int64`.

Anteriormente los floats eran considerados índices válidos en NumPy, a diferencia de Python estándar. En tu caso tienes un Warning porque estás usando una versión no actualizada de NumPy, pero **a partir de  [NumPy 1.12.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/release.html#compatibility-notes) ésto produce una excepción directamente**, como el warning avisaba en versiones previas:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

La solución obviamente pasa por pasar solo enteros a la hora de indizar con escalares sobre un array, en tu caso la solución simple es:

```
C1[(int(gen[d, 0]), d)] = C1[(int(gen[d, 0]), d)] + 1
```

o simplemente:

```
C1[int(gen[d, 0]), d] += 1
```

Si lo pensamos un poco es incongruente usar índices decimales, no queda para nada claro el resultado esperado. Imagina la siguiente situación:

- **`array[1.0]`**: no hay ningún problema de interpretación en este caso, intuitivamente es lo mismo que `array[1]`
- **`array[1.9]`**: en este caso no queda muy claro que esperamos obtener ¿`array[1]` o `array[2]`...? El mismo problema tenemos con `array[1.5]`. Rizando el rizo, por que no esperar que `array[1.5]` seleccione la fila 1 y la mitad de la 2... Definitivamente, de explícito y legible tiene poco.

Al forzar el uso de enteros, entre otras cosas, obliga a que explícitamente se defina la dirección a tomar (truncar, función suelo, función techo, etc )

> ```
> >>> import numpy as np
>
> >>> indices = np.array([-1.7, 2.8, 4.5, 6.1, 6.7])
> >>> array = np.array([2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19])
>
> >>> array[np.floor(indices).astype(int)]
> [17 5 11 17 17]
>
> >>> array[np.ceil(indices).astype(int)]
> [19 7 13 19 19]
>
> >>> array[np.rint(indices).astype(int)]
> [17 7 11 17 19]
>
> >>> array[indices.astype(int)]
> [19 5 11 17 17]
> ```